# Можно ли получить значения переменных веб-страницы в Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

```
<a href="/list/INBOX/?_rand=1131259262">
<ins>1</ins> 
   Входящие
</a>
<ins>1</ins>
```

Мне нужно на первом этапе получить значение которое соответствует входящим сообщениям,но если их 0 , то строки `<ins>1</ins>` в коде страницы нету,после некоторых действий нужно проверить изменилась ли переменная.Могу ли я вообще получить значение переменных при работе с Selenium?

Comment: ничего не понятно. какое конкретное значение вы хотите получить? тут их 3.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor первый `<ins>1</ins>`

Comment: хорошо. можете четко сказать какое конкретное значение?  с новыми условиями у вас уже 2 одинаковых элемента <ins>1</ins>

Comment: @SeniorPomidor конкретно цифру 1, после определенных действий проверить изменилось ли значение 1 или увеличилось

Answer (score 1):

В селениуме, конкретно вашу 1-цу это можно найти двумя вариантами:

1. Поиск элемента самим браузером:

`one = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/ins').text`

2. Поиск сторонними библиотеками по коду страницы (я в таких случаях использую `lxml`)

```
from lxml import html                        # импорт библиотеки HTML парсера

tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)  # сохранение HTML кода страницы в переменную
one = tree.xpath('/ins/text()')              # поиск элемента в сохранённом коде страницы
```

Первый вариант (поиск браузером) хорошо использовать когда вам необходимо выполнить интерактивную функцию (кнопки нажать, данные ввести) и найти информацию в элементах.

Второй вариант (поиск сторонней библиотекой) хорошо использовать тогда, когда после загрузки страницы можно сохранить код и закрыть браузер (сэкономить на ОЗУ и времени CPU), а всю необходимую информацию искать уже в коде в переменной (или файле).

Локация силами Селениума подобно расписана в [документации](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). Или в переводе этой документации на [habr.com](https://habr.com/ru/post/250975/)